# Getting a list of a type of Attributes beautifulsoup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I nned to get a list of all attributes from an html. I have the following code:

```
fhand = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.coinmarketcap.com")
for line in fhand:
    print(line.decode().strip())
soup = BeautifulSoup(fhand, 'html.parser')
verificar = soup.find_all("a", class_="price-toggle")
print(verificar)
```

All I get is `[]`, I want to get: `[BTC,ETH ....]`. All the price toogles here:

```
<li class="pointer"><a class="price-toggle" data-currency="xrp" data-currencyid="ripple">**XRP**</a></li>
```

Tks

Comment: Actually I can get those values with your code if to remove `for` loop (anyway, I see no sense in those lines)

Comment: @user1922364 note that coinmarketcap.com has an API that you can you at https://coinmarketcap.com/api/

Comment: @Andersson How?

Comment: @user1922364, just comment out lines `for line in fhand:
    print(line.decode().strip())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use below code to get required output:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

fhand = requests.get("http://www.coinmarketcap.com").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(fhand, 'html.parser')
verificar = soup.find_all("a", class_="price-toggle")
for item in verificar:
    print(item.text)
```

Output:

```
'USD'
'USD'
'BTC'
'ETH'
'XRP'
'BCH'
'LTC'
```